# Call your own pip-install package from command line

Tags: python, command-line, pip, executable

Not sure how to phrase this question, but what i want is similar to what [azure-cli](https://pypi.org/project/azure-cli/) does:

- You install the package (`pip install azure-cli`)
- The installation is done
- Afterwards, the `az` utility is available at the command line. You can use `az configure` and not something like `python az configure`.

How can you incorporate this in your own package?

Comment: https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve that you can add `entrypoints` argument to your `setup.py` call:

```
entrypoints={'console_scripts': ['az = my_package.some_module:main_func']}
```

See also the [setuptools documentation](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation).